# When is "Mains" or "grid" no longer the correct electrical term?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, technical

In a related question about the term for "mains" in the US ([here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20596/is-there-a-term-for-mains-power-in-american-english)), it was determined to be more often called a "grid" or "line-power".

My question is: If in let's say a customized car, that uses 12v, 120v, 24v, and the normal 5v for accessories, are all of them considered "mains"? If I build a robot that runs on 12v, but put in voltage regulator for parts that require 5v, are those still the mains?

In shorter, is "Mains" a standard for the whole grid regardless of voltage, or only the main rail before the voltage jumps or drops?

I'm sorry if this belongs in another section, I just thought I'd put it in the same as the related category.

Comment: If I'm reading the linked question correctly, then if something is not generating power, it's not part of the mains. I've never heard the term "mains" before this question, but from what I gather, neither one of the things you mention could possibly be part of it. It may be _connected_ to mains power, but it is not one of the many elements that make up the entire electrical grid.

Comment: *Mains* means connected to the external utility network (electricity, gas, water, sewerage etc.).  So in your example, a "mains" car would have to be  connected to the wall permanently: the length of the electrical cable might restrict its operating range.

Comment: As @henry says "mains" isn't correct in car. But referring to the "mains *voltage*" circuits may be helpful.

Comment: @SomethingDark This is the first time I had ever discovered that the term 'mains' was not used in America (I assume that's where you are). It is the standard way of describing any public utility supply in Britain, as Henry says. Domestically the electricity comes at 240v. *Mains* would never apply to anything generated in a car. Clearly there is a safety issue here. Any American living/visiting in Britain needs to know that 'IT'S CONNECTED TO THE MAINS' means it COULD KILL YOU.

Comment: None of those are *mains*.

Comment: "mains" is basically the alternative power source to "battery".

Answer (score 3):

Typical electrical/electronic terminology for the main eg 12V power supply running through a device is "power bus", or simply "bus". Where multiple power supply voltages are present they would be, eg, "12V bus" and "5V bus". I suspect that this terminology is used by techies even in the UK, and it's certainly well-established in the US.

(Note that "bus", by itself, implies nothing about the voltage involved -- it could be a 5V bus or a 5000V bus.  Whether the bus is dangerous to be near is up to the individual to determine based on available information on the bus's voltage and current capabilities.)

Alas, there is no simple agreed-on term in the US that conveys the meaning of UK's "mains" in a house or other building. In the US a "main" is a water or gas main, never electrical. Terms like "line power" are used.

Answer (score 2):

In British English, a *main* is a pipe or cable running along a street delivering a service to the surrounding properties - water main, gas main or electricity main.

Anything delivered by the main is described by the adjective *mains*, to distinguish it from something delivered in bottles, batteries or the like.

So anything inside a car won't be mains.  By convention, a safe low voltage produced by a step-down transformer isn't mains either.

Comment: This is technically entirely correct and accurate, but the question is explicitly tagged [american-english].

Comment: @Andrew: the question doesn't make any sense for U.S. English. None of the things the OP is asking about is called a *main.*

Comment: This is the same as in Australia. Mains power is the power you get out of the wall. It is the source of the power, not really the voltage or whatever, though usually it is assumed it is standard voltage, ie. 230V in Australia. Electricity from a battery would never be mains, even it it were 230V.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your answer with American English there is a very short answer. It's not called **mains** when electricity is involved. ;)

However, that's not very interesting. So I assume for a moment you are building a British robot.

---

The word **mains** describes the principle transport pipe/cable from or to the main supply grid. Although the power aspect is British English.

[ODO: mains](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/main#main)

> A principal pipe carrying water or gas to buildings, or taking sewage from them
>
> *British* A principal cable carrying electricity.

Moreover the [wikipedia article on mains per country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) cites the industry standard: *but IEC 60050 refers to these as 'direct plug-in equipment' defined as equipment in which **the mains plug forms an integral part of the equipment enclosure so that the equipment is supported by the mains socket-outlet.** In this article, the term 'plug' is used in the sense defined by IEC 60050.*

The socket-outlet being the usual (for your country) wall power socket. Thus everything from the local transformer up to your wall socket in your house is considered the power mains. The transformer changes the electricity from the grid voltage down to mains voltage.

---

There is however **mains electricity.** On the above wiki page you can find mains voltage (and frequency) per country. If you have build a robot which has an amazing power source which provides 230V/50Hz it would provide **mains electricity**, i.e. electricity as regular power mains would provide.

Following the concept of [mains electricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity), [mains hum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_hum) and based on the wiki article about [transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) (not the Chicago trashing ones which certainly would require that much energy) as well as considering the dictionary definition above every cable between the high voltage  electricity grid transformer and your wall socket is a power main (i.e. any cable connected to the power grid and carrying mains electricity).

I am not sure about nuclear aircraft carriers and other big structures unconnected to the power grid, but I don't think they call their major power lines aboard 'mains'. The ISS doesn't - and mostly operates on DC on lower voltages anyways.

Comment: American usage, to the extent it is used, is very different. Mains electricity specifically does not include the service connection. Mains is what the utility company has to construct back to the power plant. Service connections are what the utility company has to supply to bridge the mains to the consumers. Unless you are a refinery or steel mill, you don't have mains on your property. Mains run on a utility right-of-way. In the US, it is common to use the term mains for water, sewer, and gas, but it is not common with electrical distribution. I searched the TVA website and it doesn't appear.

Comment: As my first line says, it's not used that way in the US. That's why I assumed a British robot ;) I found the OP's original question intriguing enough to provide an answer regardless of the US not using it for electricity purposes. Where does your information that there are mains in the backbone in the US come from? I came across no such information when I investigated earlier.