# Why is home electricity supply called "mains"?

Tags: etymology, american-english, british-english

The word "mains" seems to be a widely understood synonym for home electricity supply.

Why is it called so? I always thought it was a corruption of *main [electricity supply]*.
Is it an American dialect term? I mainly came across it in American jargon context, but Wiktionary says that it's a British term. What gives?

Comment: You're reading *Wiktionary* wrong. They don't give an etymology for the English word *mains*. The unrelated ***Norman*** word *mains* is a corruption of the Latin *minus*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'll not fix it - too late.

Comment: @anatolyg As a native AmE speaker who does work in London and has regular interaction with BrE speakers, I can tell you *mains* is incontestably a BrE term, and is not used in AmE. So now I'm curious about your "American jargon" context: what was it? Who was speaking? What did they say?

Comment: Because Brits are weird.  In the US it's "electrical service" or "main power panel" or some such.  Though I assume that the NEC has a defined term, there's not a single term that would be universally recognized in the US.  (And "mains" would likely be taken to mean "water main, gas main, and sewer main".)

Comment: I think it came from **main power lines** as in ***main(line)s*** -- Food for thought?

Comment: Related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20596/is-there-a-term-for-mains-power-in-u-s-english

Comment: is it a throwback to the early C language : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter Shor mentioned, your Wiktionary link only makes a claim about the *Norman* word *mains* coming from *minus*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mains) gives for *mains*:

> *British*
>   :  of or relating to utility distribution mains mains voltage mains water

And [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=main) gives for *main*:

> Old English mægen (n.) "power, bodily strength, force, efficacy," from Proto-Germanic *maginam "power," suffixed form of PIE root *magh- "to be able, have power." Original sense preserved in phrase with might and main. **Meaning "principal channel in a utility system" is first recorded 1727 in main drain.**

Comment: etymonline doesn't mention *mains* at all; do you really have to just assume it came from *main*? English doesn't usually append "s" to an adjective to make a new word, so this requires explanation.

Comment: Etymonline mentions a usage for _main_ that almost literally follows MW's definition of _mains_. That could be coincidental, or maybe MW cannot be trusted. You yourself always assumed _mains_ came form _main_. Now you misapplied an etymology about a word in a completely different language, and you cannot trust Merriam-Webster or your own old intuition anymore?

Comment: Actually, your _own_ link give as a second definition "The **pipes** of a centralised water supply that transport the water to individual buildings." indicating a simple _plural_ of _main_. So it seems the British _mains_ with implied singular meaning may simply be originally the plural of _main_ that was used in this sense since 1727.

Comment: The OED shows that *mains* (plural form) has been used to mean "*principal channel for conveying water*" since 1727. And there's a citation from 1628 where I can't tell whether it is singular or plural. So it was just transferred to electricity. But it beats me why it's plural.

Comment: The 1727 citation: *"Where any Stock-Blocks of Wood with Plugs, or any Fire-Cocks, were made and fix'd on any Mains*." Clearly, *Mains* is singular in this. The citations alternate between using *main* and *mains*, and they're mostly British, so the singular and plural coexisted in U.K. usage for at least two centuries.